# bypass tab click in tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

My application is using a tabbed page to separate 2 main areas. Using Xamarin.Forms 4.x and Prism.

The first tab basically hosts a set of linear navigated views modelling a workflow.   It's been identified that when a user has progressed through the workflow, and accidentally taps on the current tab, the user is popped back to the start of the navigation.

Is there any way to bypass this event?

This only seems to happen on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the answer.  Works perfectly.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/144478/ios-stop-tab-re-select-pop-to-navigation-page-root